# Group a list by child elements list value in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 data classes

```
data class Channel (
        var ID : Int = 0,
        var ParametersList: List<Parameters>? = null
)

data class Parameters (
        var ParamKey : String = "",
        var ParamValue: String = ""
)
```

I have a list made out of Channel class

```
var channelList = mutableListOf<Channel>(
        Channel(0, mutableListOf<Parameters>(Parameters("SensorGroup","ABCD"),Parameters("Mode","1"))),
        Channel(1, mutableListOf<Parameters>(Parameters("SensorGroup","ABC"),Parameters("Mode","1"))),
        Channel(2, mutableListOf<Parameters>(Parameters("SensorGroup","ABCD"),Parameters("Mode","1")))
)
```

I need to group channels where ParamKey is "Sensor Group" and the ParamValues are the same

final result should be like

```
0=[Channel(ID=0, ParametersList=[Parameters(ParamKey=SensorGroup, ParamValue=ABCD), Parameters(ParamKey=Mode, ParamValue=1)]), Channel(ID=0, ParametersList=[Parameters(ParamKey=SensorGroup, ParamValue=ABCD), Parameters(ParamKey=Mode, ParamValue=1)])]

1=[Channel(ID=1, ParametersList=[Parameters(ParamKey=SensorGroup, ParamValue=ABC), Parameters(ParamKey=Mode, ParamValue=1)])]
```

I tried nested group by and filter couldnt achieve any meaning full result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupBy`. Select the keys by first finding the Parameters with the appropriate ParamKey. Since these are nullable, the lambda might return null, so it would group all the invalid items together.

The result is a `Map<String, Channel>`, where the map keys are the unique `ParamValue` values. If you don't need the map, you can just get its `values` property.

```
val result = 
  channelList.groupBy { channel -> channel.ParametersList?.firstOrNull { it.ParamKey == "SensorGroup" }?.ParamValue }
```

By the way, Kotlin convention is to use lowercase first letters for property and variable names (so they are easily distinguished from class names and objects).

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer. I was trying to loop through the ParametersList without using firstOrNull that made things complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun groupByParamKey(key: String) {
    val group = channelList.groupBy { it ->
        it.ParametersList?.first { it.ParamKey == key }?.ParamValue

    }
    print(group)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    groupByParamKey("SensorGroup")
}
```